# an object-oriented scenario with uml

Tags: uml

I have a scenario about railway system. In this system there are

Rails

- Normal : The rails don’t have any
  extern support.
- Electrified : The rails supported
  with electricity.

Trains

- High-Speed Train :This type of trains
  track on electrified rails.
- Passanger Train : Passanger trains
  can move either electrified or normal
  rails.
- Accelerated Passenger Train : This
  type of trains track on electrified
  rails. It is evolved from Passenger
  Train .
- Goods Train : A goods train can move
  both of rails but its weight makes it
  harmful for electrified rails. So it
  is not preffered.

I want to show the relation between trains and rails using uml. Obviously trains dont have rails. They just use them. But I couldn't find the true way to show the relation in class diagram. Should i use another diagram or what? thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should just model it as a [dependency](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams.html#dependency) in UML. It is usually a supplier / client relationship. In your case, the rails would be the supplier and the train the client (as in the train uses the infrastructure the rails provide). It would be a dashed arrow from 'Train' to 'Rails'. That's how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer Razzie. Here is how I made it:

I created an abstract class called "Rail". Then derived 2 sub-classes "Normal" and "Electrified". Created abstract class "Train", derived sub-classes "HighSpeedTrain", "PassengerTrain", "GoodsTrain". Also "AcceleratedPassengerTrain derives from "PassengerTrain".

Then I used dependency as u said.

- HighSpeedTrain---->Electrified
- PassengerTrain---->Normal,
  Electrified
- GoodsTrain---->Normal, Electrified
- AcceleratedPassengerTrain---->Electrified

But im not sure if it's true. Another problem; "AcceleratedPassengerTrain" should only use electrified rail. In my solution, I think it also supports normal rail because it inherits from "PassengerTrain". Please tell me what do you think about the design. Thanks for your help.